# Displaying JSON data in grid properly in a column

Tags: html, css, json, angular, typescript

I am struggling to format my HTML properly.

I am wanting to use json data to display my information in the html, however when using `display: grid`, I cannot seem to get it to output in the correct way.

In my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/grid-layout-checkboxes) I show how I would like it to look along with how it currently is...

**My problem code**

```
<div class="grid">
  <div>Car</div>
  <div>Bike</div>
  <mat-checkbox class="boxes" *ngFor="let x of data">{{x.service}}</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid {
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgray;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
```

JSON

```
data = [
      {
        "type": "car",
        "service": "speed"
      },
      {
        "type": "car",
        "service": "price"
      },
      {
        "type": "bike",
        "service": "speed"
      },
      {
        "type": "bike",
        "service": "price"
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to include the corresponding checkboxes in the parent item (car or bike in this case?), that would help with your layout and the markup would be clearer for you as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how you mean @Jake?

Comment: Check the hardcoded fork I made of your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/grid-layout-checkboxes-xpm7xt?file=src/app/app.component.css) to see what I mean.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean...
I think I need to revise the JSON structure to get what I want.

Comment: yes change your json, first have all the speed data and then price data